# LINQ with IList<SelectedItemList> Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable in which i need to convert each row into a IList

```
public IList<SelectListItem> _area = new List<SelectListItem>();
public IList<SelectListItem> _team = new List<SelectListItem>();

     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
       _area.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row[1].ToString(), Value = row[1].ToString() });
       _team.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row[0].ToString(), Value = row[0].ToString() });

            }
```

The data that is then obtained in _area looks like this :-

```
Text                     Value
OMC                      OMC
OMC                      OMC
OMC                      OMC
SIAM                     SIAM
SIAM                     SIAM
SIAM                     SIAM                     
SIAM                     SIAM                     
SIAM                     SIAM
```

I need to use LINQ to get the DISTINCT Values.

I have tried simply using :-

```
_area.Distinct();
```

But i'm left with 32 entries that i started with???

Comment: SelectedListItem doesn't override Equals, right?

Comment: You need to asign it back to the `_area` like `_area = _area.Distinct()`

Comment: @Max, you are right I think. It should override the HashCode too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_area.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key);
```

This will give you the distinct values of the areas...

how about like this

```
_area.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First());
```

Can you explain better what is Distinct, maybe you should override Equals and GetHashCode and that way It will work the Distinct, something like this

```
class Foo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var foo = obj as Foo;
        if(foo == null) return false;

        return foo.Text == Text && foo.Value == Value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Text.GetHashCode() * Value.GetHashCode() ^ 7;    
    }
}
```

and then this will work as you expect (hope so)

```
_area.Distinct();
```

Comment: I cant do this, it wont allow me to refernce x after the select command

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this `_area = _area.Distinct();`

Comment: Cannot convert IEnumerable to Ilist

Comment: I've done this, It compiles but the list is still at 32 entries, its bizarre!

Answer (score 2):

The `Distinct()` method takes a paremter of type `IEqualityComparer<T>` so in this case, you can create an equality comparer that compares two values of two `SelectListItems` like this:

```
public class SelectListItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<SelectListItem>
{
    public static SelectListItemComparer Instance = new SelectListItemComparer();
    private SelectListItemComparer() {}
    public bool Equals(SelectListItem x, SelectListItem y)
    {
        return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SelectListItem obj)
    {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var items = new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "OMC", Value = "OMC"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "OMC", Value = "OMC"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "OMC", Value = "OMC"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "SIAM", Value = "SIAM"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "SIAM", Value = "SIAM"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "SIAM", Value = "SIAM"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "SIAM", Value = "SIAM"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "SIAM", Value = "SIAM"}
                };

var comparer = new SelectListItemComparer();
var t1 = items.Distinct(SelectListItemComparer.Instance).ToList();
```

`t1` will contain only two elements now.